# Error installing cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing a cordova plugin that has dependencies to other plugins. I am not able to install the plugin without passing the **--fetch** parameter.

Here's how my plugin dependencies look like in the original plugin's xml file:

```
<dependency url="https://bitbucket.org/MY_REPO_URL" id="SOME_PLUGIN_ID"/>
<dependency url="https://bitbucket.org/MY_REPO_URL" id="SOME_OTHER_PLUGIN_ID" subdir="SOME_SUBDIR"/>
```

When I try to install the original plugin without using **--nofetch**:

```
cordova plugin add ORIGINAL_PLUGIN_ID
```

I get the following error:

```
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
No version specified for SOME_PLUGIN_NAME, retrieving version from package.json
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "SOME_PLUGIN_NAME@^2.4.3"
saving
Running command: npm install SOME_PLUGIN_NAME@^2.4.3 --production --save
Command finished with error code 0: npm install,SOME_PLUGIN_NAME@^2.4.3,--production,--save
Copying plugin ".../test/node_modules/ORIGINAL_PLUGIN_ID" => ".../test/plugins/ORIGIAL_PLUGIN_ID"
Calling plugman.install on plugin ".../test/plugins/ORIGINAL_PLUGIN_ID" for platform "android
Installing "ORIGINAL_PLUGIN_ID" for android
Running command: .../test/platforms/android/cordova/version 
Command finished with error code 0: .../test/platforms/android/cordova/version 
Dependencies detected, iterating through them...
Requesting plugin "SOME_PLUGIN_ID".
Plugin dependency "SOME_PLUGIN_ID" not fetched, retrieving then installing.
saving
Running command: npm install https://bitbucket.org/MY_REPO_URL --production --save
Command finished with error code 0: npm install,https://bitbucket.org/MY_REPO_URL,--production,--save
Failed to install 'ORIGINAL_PLUGIN_ID': Error
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:215:37
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-fetch/node_modules/q/q.js:864:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-fetch/node_modules/q/q.js:890:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-fetch/node_modules/q/q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-fetch/node_modules/q/q.js:808:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-fetch/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-fetch/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-fetch/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://bitbucket.org/MY_REPO_URL via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined
```

If I use **--nofetch**, the installation works perfectly.

```
cordova plugin add ORIGINAL_PLUGIN_NAME --nofetch
```

I'd like to know if there is anything I can do so that I can add the plugin without using **--nofetch**

Comment: I haven't tested setting up the dependencies through npm, I wonder if this would fix it or I'd have the plugins added twice then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved this by publishing the dependencies in npm and removing the subdir and url attributes (just adding the plugin id).

Now we can add the plugins without **--nofetch** to a project.

I also found out that the **subdir** feature is being deprecated internally in cordova as npm becomes the default option. Unfortunately, this is not documented and the subdir option for dependencies is [still documented](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#dependency) as a supported and non-deprecated feature.